# Users with high reputation on several Stack Exchange network sites

Tags: support, reputation, data-explorer, statistics, network-profile

It's easy to track down the users with most reputation on a particular network site. I am much more interested in those universal geniuses who have earned a lot of reputation on many different sites. Is there a way to ask the Stack Exchange Data Explorer about, say, people with more than 5k reputation on at least two sites?

Comment: Ah, the dreaded cross-site query. It's technically possible, but a pain in the butt to write (think querying ~120 separate databases...).

Comment: "universal geniuses". You misunderstand what reputation means. It is a measure of community trust in a user, and nothing else.

Comment: You'll need to consider that it's much, much harder to get reputation in the smaller sites of the network. 5K rep on a young beta site is as awesome as 50K on Stack Overflow, if not more.

Comment: "universal geniuses" being tongue-in-cheek for people who are trusted on a lot of stackexchange sites and therefore seem to be able to provide expertise in a lot of different fields.

Comment: While @Louis is right, I think your meaning was obvious with "universal geniuses".

Comment: I'm not a native English speaker so I felt that clarification necessary in case I used an inappropriate term.

Comment: @Yannis that may true in general but it does seem to vary by the site and it's very personal in any case. For example on the workplace, recently out of beta, avg votes per q/a is 9/6, on cross-validated it is 3/3, on mathematica 5/5, c.f. the main sites stackoverflow and math which are lower at around 2/2(see http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/81058/average-score-for-questions-and-answers?opt.textResults=true). Personally, as a programmer using 4 sites on and off, I found stackoverflow somewhere in the middle in terms of ease of gaining reputation (whatever that means!:).

Comment: @michaelb958 The difficulty of cross-site queries is overrated. It is actually not too hard by using built-in system tables.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have created a query to find your definition of universal geniuses, which is [available here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/220081/find-users-with-highest-rep-on-multiple-sites?MinReputation=5000&OnMinSites=2).

The query basically loops through all available databases (excluding meta sites where user reputation is the same as on its corresponding site) and picks users with more than `n` reputation (default 5000) on at least `n` different sites (default 2).

It reveals that by your definition, [Gilles](https://stackexchange.com/users/164368/gilles) is currently the "most universal genius", as s/he has more than 5000 reputation on the 11 different sites: *Unix:211723, Meta:50246, StackOverflow:37746, SuperUser:30930, French:26017, Ubuntu:22065, Scifi:19700, Security:17464, Cs:14029, Travel:8984, ServerFault:6149.*

**Query:**

```sql
-- Select all valid databases.
select dbid, name
into #dbs
from master..sysdatabases
where name not in ('Data.StackExchange', 'master', 'model', 'msdb', 'tempdb')
  and right(name, 5) <> '.Meta'
   or name = 'StackExchange.Meta'

-- Loop through databases to find all users with high enough reputation.
create table #topusers (
  accountid int,
  userid int,
  rep int,
  site varchar(40)
)
declare @id int, @db varchar(40), @sql varchar(max)
while (select count(*) from #dbs) > 0
begin
  select top 1 @id = dbid, @db = name from #dbs
  set @sql = '
    insert into #topusers
    select AccountId, Id, Reputation, ''' + @db + '''
    from [' + @db + ']..[Users]
    where Reputation > ' + cast(##MinReputation:int?5000## as varchar(max))
  exec (@sql)
  delete from #dbs where dbid = @id
end

-- Summarize the results nice and clean.
select 
  'https://stackexchange.com/users/' + cast(accountid as varchar(15)) 
    + '|' + cast(accountid as varchar(15)) as [Account Link],
  count(accountid) as [Site count],
  stuff (
    (select ', ' + 
     case when left(site, 14) = 'stackexchange.' 
       then substring(site, 15, len(site))
       else site
     end + ':' + cast(rep as varchar(max)) 
       from #topusers 
       where (accountid = u.accountid)
       order by rep desc
       for xml path(''),type
       ).value('(./text())[1]','varchar(max)')
    ,1,2,'') as [Site:rep]
from #topusers u
group by accountid having count(accountid) >= ##OnMinSites:int?2##
order by count(accountid) desc
```

Comment: I don't think it's necessary to write "s/he" when the display name is *Gilles*... it's more telling than, say, *Banana*. :)

Comment: I found it interesting to add a `(select top 1 Rep from #topusers where accountid = u.accountid order by Rep desc) as 'Top Site Rep'` column.

Comment: @mmyers You can just use `max(rep) as 'Top Site Rep'`

Comment: Typo alert: Meta SE is id `37`, not `38`. ([source](http://data.stackexchange.com/meta.stackexchange/query/91025/query-stackexchange-databases-names))

Comment: @michaelb958 Thank you, I fixed it with a cleaner solution - instead of adding `Meta.StackExchange` after, the query now just doesn't filter it out in the first place.